# javascript button stops working after close

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a button that opens a dialog and when I close the dialog it stops working.  When I save on the dialog screen it continues to work fine.

This is the button that opens the dialog:

```
<button class="actionbutton" type="button" onclick="addLitigant();">Add Litigant To Case(s)</button>
```

The code it calls:

```
function addLitigant(){
    console.log("Calling addLitigant()");
    editDialog.extendedDialog('loadUrl','CRFilingLitigantDialog.do?action=addLitigant', 'Add Litigant');
}
```

The close code on the dialog screen:

```
param['buttons'].push(
        {
            id: "closeButton",
            text: "(C)lose",
            accessKey: "c",
            click: function () {
                jQuery(this).extendedDialog('close');
                jQuery(this).html('');

            }
        }
    );
```

The save button code:

```
function () { 
                        console.log("clicking Save");
                        jQuery('#toAssign option').each(function(){
                            jQuery(this).attr('selected',true);
                        });

                        jQuery('#toUnassign option').each(function(){
                            jQuery(this).attr('selected',true);
                        });

                        editDialog.extendedDialog('postUrl', {url: 'CRFilingLitigantDialog.do?action=updateLitigant', formId: '#crFilingLitigantDialogForm', success: function(){
                            litigantTabGet('CRFilingLitigantDetail.do', null);
                            editDialog.extendedDialog ('destroy');
                        }});
                    }
```

We are using jquery 1.6.2. I have tried adding console.log statements to the addLitigant() function but when I come back from the close it doesn't call anything in the console.  If I refresh the page it does begin to work again until we close from the dialog.

This is the immediate function that is on the page that opens the dialog

```
jQuery(function(){
    console.log("function");

    verificationDialog = jQuery('<div id="verificationDialog"></div>').clerkReviewDialogTemplate({
        height:600,
        width:800,
        title: "Compare Eflex and Icis"
    });

    compareDialog = jQuery('<div id="comparisonDialog"></div>').clerkReviewDialogTemplate({
        height:400,
        width:500,
        title: "Imported Person"
    });

    editDialog = jQuery('<div id="editDialog"></div>').clerkReviewDialogTemplate({
        height:600,
        width:700,
        title: "Edit Litigant",
        buttons: [
            {
                id: "save",
                text: "S(a)ve",
                accessKey: "a",
                click: function () { 
                    console.log("clicking Save");
                    jQuery('#toAssign option').each(function(){
                        jQuery(this).attr('selected',true);
                    });

                    jQuery('#toUnassign option').each(function(){
                        jQuery(this).attr('selected',true);
                    });

                    editDialog.extendedDialog('postUrl', {url: 'CRFilingLitigantDialog.do?action=updateLitigant', formId: '#crFilingLitigantDialogForm', success: function(){
                        litigantTabGet('CRFilingLitigantDetail.do', null);
                        editDialog.extendedDialog ('destroy');
                    }});
                }
            }
        ]
    });

    jQuery('.saveOnChange').bind('change', function(){
        updateLitigants();
    });

    jQuery('.pin').icisAutocomplete({
        mustMatch: true,
        source: function(request, response){
            getQuickAccess(request, response);
        },
        change: function(event, ui){
            updateLitigants();
        }}).each(function(index){
            var data = jQuery(this).data('staging-json');

                jQuery(this).bind('keydown', function(event){
                    return f5_handler({
                        event: event,
                        onf5key: function(){
                            var popup = people_popup({elem: this, event: event, data: data, success: function(data){
                                if(data['pin'] != 'null'){
                                    jQuery(event.currentTarget).val(data['pin']);
                                }
                                if(data['masterPin'] != 'null'){
                                    jQuery('#'+jQuery(event.currentTarget).attr('masterPinField')).val(data['masterPin']);
                                }
                                compareDialog.extendedDialog('close');
                                updateLitigants();
                            }});
                            compareImportedLitigant(data['id'], popup);
                        }
                    });
                });
        });
});
```

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: What kind of UI you're using? Cause it doesn't seem to be a normal JavaScript click!

Comment: We are using jQuery-ui, is that what you mean?

Comment: I don't have any experience with jQuery UI, but it was better to mention it in the tags for people like me that haven't used it yet.

Comment: Delegating the events would not do the job? `$('document').on('change',function (event){ /* my onChange event function */});`

Answer (score 0):

looks like a post back issue that makes you lose you bind events - this is the only thing that could cause losing button event - try to replace your immediate function with

```
function pageLoad() {}
```

see this [$(document).ready() and pageLoad() are not the same!](http://encosia.com/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/)

might help

Comment: I am not sure I understand, you want me to replace my jQuery(function(){ with function pageLoad() { ?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I said your addLitigant function is posting back you page and when ever this happens it ignores any thing inside your document ready function to fix this you need to have your code in pageload function this function will be render after each post back if this doesn't work then you have a global pageload function inside your project .... Try this and see if it will work and if you can post more code this will be helpful

Comment: I tried converting the immediate function that I added above to a pageLoad() function and it still stops working.

Answer (score 0):

I compared this code to an older version. I noticed that it worked in an older version and I compared the two.  The older version had a change in the edit dialog code, I added the close code to it and it now works.

```
 editDialog = jQuery('<div id="editDialog"></div>').clerkReviewDialogTemplate({
            height:600,
            width:700,
            title: "Edit Litigant",
            close: function(){
                litigantTabGet('CRFilingLitigantDetail.do', null);
                editDialog.extendedDialog ('destroy').remove();
            },
            buttons: [
                {
                    id: "save",
                    text: "S(a)ve",
                    accessKey: "a",
                    click: function () {
                        jQuery('#toAssign option').each(function(){
                            jQuery(this).attr('selected',true);
                        });

                        jQuery('#toUnassign option').each(function(){
                            jQuery(this).attr('selected',true);
                        });

                        editDialog.extendedDialog('postUrl', {url: 'CRFilingLitigantDialog.do?action=updateLitigant', formId: '#crFilingLitigantDialogForm', success: function(){
                            litigantTabGet('CRFilingLitigantDetail.do', null);
                            editDialog.extendedDialog ('destroy');

                        }});
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
```